# SVG under SVG in HTML5

Tags: html, svg

I have written a small sample in which I have included svg file my code is below

```
  <svg id="cityBox" width="600" height="400">
    <text x="300" y="50" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="36" text-anchor="middle"
    stroke="#000000" fill="#000000">
    Survivng the Zombie 
    </text>
    <image id="human" x="250" y="175" width="50" height="50" xlink:href=image1.svg/>
    </svg>
```

On browsing the web page I see is below

[image]

The svg image is still not coming and showing an image break icon.

What is wrong that I am doing here?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine, I do see an image when I replace the link with a different resource. I suspect your image1.svg is either non-existent, mis-spelt, or specified with the wrong path. For this to work, there should be an actual `image1.svg` at your `localhost:62601/SVG`.

Comment: What browser have you used?

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 28.0.1500.63

Comment: I have got the issue, it seems that on opening the html file from the folder location there is no problem, that works fine but,

Comment: since I am using VS 2010 as my IDE, and when I right click on the html file, and click on view in browser, somehow the image is not getting shown. This seems to be an IDE issue to me.

Comment: You probably just typed it wrong when posting (sorry if that's the case) but you either have to leave a space before the self-closing upper slash on the image tag or put the image path inside quotes. I would do both but if you do none it wont work.